# Suggest character name for a Monk

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, monk

I'm going to play a Monk character soon and I'm stuck a little bit with choosing a proper name for him. The character is calm, considered, has a buddhist type personality. I'm looking for a (probably chinese) name for him what is sounds "cool", but also have a meaning related to his attributes.

Could you give me some examples to choose from or a good source to look at?

Comment: Im not really sure if this is the right kind of question for this site.

Comment: This might be better suited for the japanese or Chinese Stack exchange? Thats just a guess though, as I dont know their rules at all.

Answer (score 0):

The internet is full of name generators. You can use them for inspiration or even take a complete name if you like it. [Chinese fantasy name generator](http://fantasynamegenerators.com/chinese_names.php#).

You could also use a translate site like [Google translate](https://translate.google.com) to translate words into, for example, Chinese and use that as a base for your name.

Comment: Was just going to suggest Google translate too - e.g. https://translate.google.co.uk/?hl=en-GB&tab=mT&authuser=0#en/zh-CN/Calm%20Storm - however, probably best to close this Q as a duplicate